# Why do snapshots consume much less space than the data which is changed after they have been taken?

Tags: zfs, size, snapshot

Although I am using ZFS since quite a while, I am still failing to understand some aspects of it from time to time. Currently I am trying to understand how ZFS snapshots take up space on the disk and why that space is much smaller then I would expect.

My problem is best explained by an example. I have a VM running from a **ZVOL with no compression** (`compression=off`). These are the snapshots of that volume:

```
root@server01 ~ # zfs list -r -t all -o name,type,available,used,referenced,usedbyrefreservation,usedbydataset,usedbychildren,usedbysnapshots,volsize,refreservation,reservation rpool01/vm-server01
NAME                                       TYPE      AVAIL   USED  REFER  USEDREFRESERV  USEDDS  USEDCHILD  USEDSNAP  VOLSIZE  REFRESERV  RESERV
rpool01/vm-server01                        volume    1.60T  1.97T  1.01T             0B   1.01T         0B      985G    1.50T       none    none
rpool01/vm-server01@Y-2020-05-27-11-35-15  snapshot      -  1.06G  1.00T              -       -          -         -       1T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@T-2020-06-02-11-41-15  snapshot      -  1.04G  1.00T              -       -          -         -       1T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@Y-2021-04-24-05-36-24  snapshot      -  1.66G  1.00T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@M-2021-04-24-21-22-30  snapshot      -  3.78G  1.01T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@T-2021-04-25-14-27-15  snapshot      -     0B  1.01T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@T-2021-04-25-14-27-30  snapshot      -     0B  1.01T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@W-2021-04-25-21-55-43  snapshot      -   555M  1.01T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@D-2021-04-27-17-49-00  snapshot      -  1.52G  1.01T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@D-2021-04-29-08-48-16  snapshot      -  1.06G  1.01T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@D-2021-05-03-09-42-01  snapshot      -  1.08G  1.01T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
rpool01/vm-server01@D-2021-05-04-12-12-01  snapshot      -  45.3M  1.01T              -       -          -         -    1.50T          -       -
```

So far, so good. The worrying thing is:

For example, after having taken the next-to-last snapshot, I have copied about `18 GB` of new data to the running VM. However, that snapshot's `USED` size is reported as `1.08 GB`. In my understanding, when a snapshot has been taken, it is read-only and thus actually can't increase. But of course, the file system needs space to record the changes that happen to the dataset / ZVOL afterwards, and that's what it is reported as a snapshot's `USED` size (please correct me if I am wrong).

As a second, more extreme example, that VM ran about seven hours after I had taken snapshot `@T-2021-04-25-14-27-30`. I am absolutely sure that quite a few GB of data have been changed in the VM during that time. But that snapshot's `USED` size even is reported to be `0`.

I have found a weird way to see how much data has actually changed after a snapshot has been taken: We can "simulate" sending the snapshot by something like the following command line (command on the first line, output on the following two lines):

```
root@server01 ~ # zfs send -v -n -R -i rpool01/vm-server01@D-2021-05-03-09-42-01 rpool01/vm-server01@D-2021-05-04-12-12-01
send from @D-2021-05-03-09-42-01 to rpool01/vm-server01@D-2021-05-04-12-12-01 estimated size is 18.6G
total estimated size is 18.6G
```

(`-n` tells zfs to not do anything, but report what it would do; `-v` means verbose; `-i` means incremental; for `-R`, please have a look into `man zfs`, it's too long to explain here)

Here we see that incrementally sending the last snapshot based on the next-to-last snapshot would take approximately `18 GB`, which nearly exactly is the amount of data which has been changed in or added to the VM, respectively, after `@D-2021-05-03-09-42-01` had been taken, before `D-2021-05-04-12-12-01` had been taken. In other words, ZFS knows how much data has been altered between the next-to-last and the last snapshot, but still for the next-to-last snapshot shows a `USED` value of `1.08 GB` instead of about `18 GB`.

Could anybody please give an explanation?

P.S. I already have read several articles about how to interpret `zfs list`'s size values, and I have understood that it can get quite hard to understand when `reservations`, `refreservations`, nested datasets, clones, snapshots and the like come into play, but the situation here is quite simple, isn't it? Anyway, I didn't see a hint about the difference between the expected and the reported size of snapshots yet.

Comment: was the 18GB of data highly compressible? plain text files?  It's not unusual to get 90% or better compression with highly repetitive text like log files.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to mention that compression is turned off for that ZVOL. I'll ad this to the question. Anyways, in this case, it was 18 GB / about 15.000 messages of email data which has been copied into a IMAP server's mail store which is running in the VM. However, (in other environments) I have observed the same phenomenon after having copied 50 GB of non-compressible data (JPEG and AVC).

Comment: not an answer to your question, but why disable compression for that zvol?  you'd likely get a massive I/O performance boost if the mail store was compressed.  and use a lot less space on your pool.   The're really no good reason not to use compression unless the dataset/zvol is going to mostly store data that's already compressed.

Comment: Thanks again. Compression is disabled because the file system in the VM will be encrypted later (by means of the software in the VM itself, in this case Veracrypt / Windows). Therefore, sadly, data won't be compressible from the perspective of ZFS, and turning on compression on that ZVOL would worsen things instead of improving them.

Comment: Ok, that may be your answer then.  Veracrypt may be (probably is) compressing the data as it's encrypting it - it's fairly common for encryption SW to do this.   Check the Veracrypt docs to find out.   If it is, then ZFS probably only sees the post-encrypted+compressed data when it's written to the zvol (depends on what you mean by "encrypted *later*").

Comment: BTW, I've been using ZFS on linux for over 10 years now, and haven't noticed this....but I don't really pay much attention to snapshot sizes unless my backup pool is running low on space.  Then I'll start running `zfs list -o space -r` and the like to hunt for old snapshots to delete.   The only thing I have to complain about is that while zfs snapshots are lightweight, it still takes a long time to list them when you've got over a million snapshots from the last several years.

Comment: Thanks again. I should have expressed myself more clearly. The encryption will happen later - currently nothing is encrypted. The ZFS compression being turned off is due to the fact that the VM's file system *will* be encrypted *in the future*; that is, as soon as everything in the VM runs smoothly. Anyways, VeraCrypt does not compress anything. It works simply and reliably: It decrypts every sector of the HDD when the O/S loads this sector, and encrypts every sector as it is written. Simply put, that's all it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now can answer my own question. Since I've got no reply for a few days here, I've asked the question on the ZFS on Linux mailing list as well, and two members named "Greek" and "Stefan Ring" have explained the subject to me. The thread is [here](https://zfsonlinux.topicbox.com/groups/zfs-discuss/T832a89c914b9c76a).

To summarize:

The `USED` size of a snapshot (in contrast to my first understanding) does not reflect the amount of data which was written to the ZVOL since that snapshot has been taken, before the next snapshot has been taken.

Instead, it is the amount of data which is *unique* to that snapshot. In other words, it is the amount of disk space which would be freed if you would delete that snapshot.

Now it is clear why this never is the amount of data you have added to the ZVOL before the next snapshot has been taken. To come back to my example: I have added about 18 GB to the ZVOL after the next-to-last snapshot has been taken.

However, if I would delete that snapshot, those 18 GB of data of course would still be in the ZVOL. Therefore, that space would not be freed by deleting that snapshot.

Instead, only about 1 GB (the `USED` size) would be freed; only that space is unique to the snapshot and is probably occupied by a mixture of metadata to manage the snapshot and payload data which has been deleted or changed (but not added) after that snapshot.

If you want to see the amount of data which has been written to a snapshot since it has been taken and before the next snapshot has been taken, use the `WRITTEN` property.

The difference between `USED` and `WRITTEN` is clearly documented in the `zfs` manual. Although I have read that manual more than one time, I obviously have missed the `WRITTEN` property.